# Swift protocol with lazy property requirement

Tags: swift, lazy, protocols

First question here on CodeReview. I was directed here from a question I asked on SO: [Swift protocol with lazy property - Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: '$0' is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58364613/swift-protocol-with-lazy-property-cannot-use-mutating-getter-on-immutable-valu/58364648).

Goal: Create a protocol that allows lazy computation of a property for structs that conform to the protocol. The computation is intensive and should only be executed once, hence the lazy requirement.

So, after lots of reading (eg [Swift Struct with Lazy, private property conforming to Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202834/swift-struct-with-lazy-private-property-conforming-to-protocol), where I based this code on) and trial and error, I came up with something that works:

```
import Foundation

protocol Foo {
    var footype: Double { mutating get }

    func calculateFoo() -> Double
}

struct Bar: Foo {
    private lazy var _footype: Double = {
        let value = calculateFoo()

        return value
    }()

    var footype: Double {
        mutating get {
            return _footype
        }
    }

    func calculateFoo() -> Double {
        print("calc")
        return 3.453
    }
}
```

Testing this in a Playground:

```
var bar = Bar()
print(bar.footype)
print(bar.footype)
```

And the output is:

```
calc
3.453
3.453
```

So it is working. But it feels like a hack using `_footype`

Also in the comments, it was suggested that

> However, I would not put calculateFoo in the protocol because it sounds like an implementation detail.

Appreciate any comments and/or improvements.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the additional `_footype` variable and a computer “wrapper” property. The protocol requirement can be satisfied with a lazy stored property:

```
struct Bar: Foo {
    lazy var footype = calculateFoo()

    func calculateFoo() -> Double {
        print("calc")
        return 3.453
    }
}
```

Now `footype` is read-only for instances of type `Foo`

```
var foo: Foo = Bar()
print(foo.footype)
foo.footype = 12.3 // Error: Cannot assign to property: 'footype' is a get-only property
```

but as a property of `Bar` it is read-write:

```
var bar = Bar()
print(bar.footype)
bar.footype = 12.3 // OK
```

If assigning to the `footype` property should be inhibited then you can mark it with a `private(set)` access modifier:

```
struct Bar: Foo {
    private(set) lazy var footype = calculateFoo()

    func calculateFoo() -> Double {
        print("calc")
        return 3.453
    }
}

var bar = Bar()
print(bar.footype)
bar.footype = 12.3 // Cannot assign to property: 'footype' setter is inaccessible
```

With respect to

> However, I would not put calculateFoo in the protocol because it sounds like an implementation detail.

Yes, in your current code it is an implementation detail of the `Bar` class. The only use would be that a caller can “enforce” the evaluation:

```
var foo: Foo = Bar()
foo.calculateFoo()
```

The situation would be different if there were a way to provide a default implementation in an extension method:

```
protocol Foo {
    var footype: Double { mutating get }

    func calculateFoo() -> Double
}

extension Foo {
    var footype: Double {
        // Call calculateFoo() on first call only ...
    }
}
```

so that conforming to the protocol is sufficient, i.e. `Bar` only has to implement the `calculateFoo()` method, but not the `footype` property.

But I am not aware of a way to do this *lazily* so that the function is called only once. The reason is that extensions cannot add stored properties to a type.

For sub*classes* of `NSObject` you can come around this problem with “associated objects,” but not for structs.

Comment: Yes, `footype` is calculated only, never set. So, just to be sure, to be able to use the `lazy` property, I need to use `mutating` in `var footype: Double { mutating get }` in the protocol?

Comment: @Koen: Yes (unless you make Foo a “class-only” protocol: `protocol Foo: class {...}` and `Bar` a class instead of a struct).

Comment: yes, it has to be a struct, due to other parts of my code.

Comment: And the implementation of `calculateFoo()` is different for the various structs that conform to `Foo`, so they must all implement it for their specific case.

Comment: There is no need to wrap `calculateFoo()` call into closure. You can write `lazy var footype: Double = calculateFoo()`, and it will work as expected, `calculateFoo` will be called just once, and only when the variable is accessed for the first time.

Comment: @EgorKomarov: You are completely right, thanks!